# Symmetric Power Spectum for a signal plotted with python

Tags: python, signals, filtering, fft

I'm trying to filter a signal using a simple filter and I wanted to plot the power spectrum of this signal but I dunno why it's symmetric

[image]

I dunno if it's correct and if there is an explanation for it
the other question is that I didn't know how to pick the frequencies to plot in the PSD

Comment: You should expect Hermitian symmetry for the PSD of real-valued signal (see e.g. [this section of the DFT page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#DFT_of_real_and_purely_imaginary_signals)). Many proofs out there (such as [this one](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/Symmetry.html)). Perhaps you could show us the code you have so far to plot your PSD, and let us know whether you'd like to restrict the plot to a specific frequency range, or get a subset of the data to plot (and maybe also do something else with it).

Comment: yes exactly I converted it from a two-sided power spectrum to a single-sided power spectrum by taking all values from 0 to N/2 and now everything is fine. thank you